# How to disable external access to a property?

Tags: swift

If I have got this class

```
class Test {
    var myVariable = 2

}
```

My problem is that if I create an instance of this class, I can access directly to my myVariable property, I tried to disable it using access controllers, but it didn't changed anything.
How can I disable (or even hide) it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `private` attribute:

```
class Test {
    private var myVariable = 2
}
```

There are 3 access levels:

- `public`: accessible to all
- `internal`: accessible in the current module only
- `private`: accessible from any code in the same file

If no modifier is specified, it is defaulted to `internal`

More info: [Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-XID_29)

Comment: Hum... I am still able to do that :

class Test {
    private var myVariable = 2
    
}

var myObject = Test()

myObjet.myVariable = 2

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"?

Comment: Well, I mean that I can still access to myVariable using the dot notation on any instance of my class.

Comment: Ok added description of what each access level means. `private` in swift means private to the file, and not to the class like in other languages.

Comment: Ok thank you, so there is no way to make it private to the class only ? Did Apple explained this design choice ?

Comment: [This post from the Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=11) goes into some detail about why access control is the way it is. The big reason I see for the "same file" `private` modifier is that operators need to be declared at top-level scope, and thus wouldn't have access to a type's private members if `private` scoped things inside the class declaration.

Comment: I disagree with Apple implementation, because in my opinion classes and files are 2 unrelated entities just like apples and boxes are unrelated entities - although I can put apples in boxes. And I miss a `protected` access modifier, which somehow limits the way I am used to code. But that's what we have in our toolset, so happy or not, we have to live with that. And by the way, no, there is no way to make it private to the class only